# How to get results from database in asp.net mvc 3 using ADO.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net

I wrote model class which returns a List then i pass it to view, but when the page is requested the view call the model many times and then crash the page, here's my code please help me I am new to asp.net MVC

Model

```
public List<string> DoWork()
    {
        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Connection String Here"))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Column1 FROM Table1", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        results.Add(rdr.GetString(0));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyData data = new MyData();
        return View(data);
    }
```

View

```
<ul>
@for (int i = 0; i <@Model.DoWork().Count; i++)
{
<li>
  @Model.DoWork()[i]
</li>
}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that the DB layer and View layer should be separated.
This being said, you should get your DB entities in your controller action method, not in the view, and use a ViewModel pattern to spit it to the view.In your case, you have a simple view model, IEnumerable, but it can be any entity.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyData data = new MyData();
        IEnumerable<string> thelist = data.DoWork();
        return View(thelist);
    }
```

and in yout View, use the IEnumerable as your model, and loop though it , not calling the DB to fetch your data:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
......
@foreach(string s in Model)
{
  <li>@s<li>
}
```

Comment: the way i wrote the code, is it a good approach, your comments, or how can i wrote it more better

Comment: @JeloMelo best practices can be found on asp.net/mvc. It's recomended for scalable applications Repository pattern, and DI(dependency injection) and IoC(inversion of control).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `DoWork` method each time you want to use a result...

Store the result in a variable, and use that, instead.

```
<ul>
@{ List<string> works = Model.DoWork(); }
@for (int i = 0; i < works.Count; i++)
{
<li>
  @works[i]
</li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: the way i wrote the code, is it a good approach, your comments, or how can i wrote it more better.